# Apple Mini DisplayPort to VGA adapter and DDC/CI communication

Tags: macbook-pro, displayport, vga-adapter, vga

I developed a Cocoa based OS X app to set brightness and contrast of a monitor using DDC/CI communication.

The app works perfectly using a Mac Pro attached to a BenQ DDC/CI capable monitor. It works with every connection interface: VGA, DVI and HDMI.

If I attach the same BenQ monitor to a MacBook via Apple Mini DisplayPort to VGA adapter, the app isn't able to send DDC/CI commands to the monitor...it reports that the monitor isn't DDC/CI capable.

I'm sure it is not an issue related to the app. It detects correctly both of the monitor (the internal and the external one) and I'm sure that I'm sending DDC/CI commands to the external monitor and not to the internal one.

Does Apple Mini DisplayPort to VGA adapter support DDC/CI?

Comment: How this question is supposed to be off-topic? It's exactly about Apple hardware..

Comment: Calling this off topic is silly. @Andrea3000, are you able to share this app? I am searching for a software tool that can set monitor brightness and contrast. Is it for sale?

Comment: I have the same question, and I'm looking for a utility to change backlighting through DDC. No point though if the adapter doesn't support it. The one program I tried didn't work.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this problem? I have a similar problem but with DVI-D-VGA connector https://items.s2.citilink.ru/1062424_v01_b.jpg